# How to show method declaration in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

is there any way to show function declaration. e.g  what it takes as parameters and what it returns in CLI? as like "tinker in laravel" 
I searched over internet but found nothing.

Comment: No, there is no built-in documentation available on the CLI. Just read the docs.

Comment: @Bergi is there any npm module that does the same?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question. To find out what a function looks like, including its parameters (and all its code including what it returns), you can do a (slightly dirty) hack like this:

```
function a(b,c) {
    return b + ", " + c;
}
console.log(a.toString());
```

Output:

```
'function b(a,b){return a+" " + b}'
```

Alternatively, if you are looking for documentation, for most NPM modules and note itself, there is solid API documentation. See https://nodejs.org/api/ for example.

Comment: but I want to see the built in method or from the module. is it possible in command line?

Comment: There is no such thing. What you're left with is the API documentation for whichever module you are using.